Korean characters break when inserting Excel data into MySQL using PHP
I am trying to upload a list of data from an Excel file to a database.
So far, uploading the Excel file and inserting the data into the database is working fine. However, when I check the data using echo, all the Korean characters are broken (and they also appear broken in the database). I have confirmed that the CSV file's encoding is UTF-8.
I have tried various encoding conversion methods, such as iconv(), but none of them seem to fix the issue.
The PHP version on the server where I am developing is below 5.3. Interestingly, the same source code and file work perfectly fine on another server environment.
Could anyone provide a solution or explanation for this issue?
Thank you.
    // excel upload
    case "faExcel" :
        // file check
        if ( empty( $_FILES['xls_file'][name] ) ) {
            // $altMsg = 'CSV파일을 선택하지 않으셨습니다.';
            echo '파일을 선택하지 않으셨습니다.';
            exit;
        } 

        // excel check
        else if ( !preg_match("/.csv$/i", $_FILES['xls_file'][name] ) ) {
            // $altMsg = 'CSV 파일만 업로드 하실 수 있습니다.'; 
            echo 'CSV 파일만 업로드 하실 수 있습니다.';
            exit;
        }

        // error check
        if ($_FILES['xls_file']['error'] == 0 && $_FILES['xls_file']['size'] > 0) {
            $cnt = 0;

            $fp = fopen($_FILES['xls_file'][tmp_name], 'r');
            

            while($row = fgetcsv($fp, 1000, ',')) {
                if($cnt === 0) {
                    // 첫 번째 행은 헤더이므로 건너뜀
                    $cnt++;
                    continue;
                }

                // 데이터가 없는 경우를 건너뛰기 (빈 행)
                if (count($row) <= 1 && empty($row[0])) {
                    continue;
                }
                

                // CSV 파일의 각 열을 데이터베이스 필드에 매핑
                // $fa_group = $fa_group; 
                // $fa_name = $row[1];
                // $fa_zipcode = $row[2];
                // $fa_address = $row[3];
                // $fa_road_address = $row[4];
                // $fa_address_sub = $row[5];
                // $fa_email = $row[6];
                // $fa_phone = $row[7];
                // $fa_mobile = $row[8];
                // $fa_memo = $row[9];
                // $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
                // $regdt = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

                $query = "INSERT INTO ".GD_FAVORITE_ADDRESS." SET
                    fa_group = '$fa_group',
                    fa_name = '".$row[1]."',
                    fa_zipcode = '".$row[2]."',
                    fa_address = '".$row[3]."',
                    fa_road_address = '".$row[4]."',
                    fa_address_sub = '".$row[5]."',
                    fa_email = '".$row[6]."',
                    fa_phone = '".$row[7]."',
                    fa_mobile = '".$row[8]."',
                    fa_memo = '".$row[9]."',
                    ip = '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."',
                    regdt = NOW() ";


                // if($db->query($query)) {
                //  $rst[0]++;
                // }else {
                //  $rst[1]++;
                // }

                $cnt++;
                echo "test: " . $cnt . "<br>";
                echo $row[0]."<br>";
                echo $row[1]."<br>";
                echo $row[2]."<br>";
                echo $row[3]."<br>";
                echo $row[4]."<br>";
                echo $row[5]."<br>";
                echo $row[6]."<br>";
                echo $row[7]."<br>";
                echo $row[8]."<br>";
                echo $row[9]."<br>";
                echo "<br>";
            }
        }

        exit;

        msg("등록결과 성공(".$rst[0]."), 실패".$rst[1].")","./favoriteAddress_list.php","parent.document");
        break;
}


Always use prepared statements / parameterized queries. Never concatenate data into your query string, it doesn't handle all text well and is open to SQL Injection Attacks
